# wxFloatingPoint is not working

Tags: dialog, floating-point, wxwidgets, validation

I am using wxFloatingPoint format my text control to show two digits after point.

I describe them in my dialogs init();

```
    double sayi;
    wxFloatingPointValidator<double>
    val(2, &sayi, wxNUM_VAL_ZERO_AS_BLANK);
    val.SetRange(0.0, 360.0);
    TextCtrl1 = new wxTextCtrl(this, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxPoint(120,96), wxDefaultSize, wxTE_READONLY|wxTE_CENTRE|wxNO_BORDER, val, _T("ID_TEXTCTRL3"));
```

And I set my text controls label in another function which is getting data from udp:

```
void OgrenciDialog::VerileriYaz(string hiz, string yon)
{

    TextCtrl1->SetValue(yon);
}
```

But it still shows values like 12,4325643346.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The validator should transfer the value of the associated variable to the control if the latter is inside a dialog and you don't override its data transfer methods. However, from the code you show, you're passing a pointer to a local variable to the validator which means that it will be using a dangling pointer by then. Typically you would use a `OgrenciDialog::m_sayi` to ensure that the pointer remains valid.

Also, why do you call `SetLabel()` on wxTextCtrl? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: I have notieced SetLabel() too. A typo.

And I declared m_sayi in header file. Initialize it to 124.5433. It is Ok starting. But after setting in function still shows too many digits after point.

Comment: I didn't even realize the problem was too high precision, "not working" is a bit more critical than that, perhaps you should update your title. But I don't see why the precision is not set to 2 as expected, you should try to reproduce the problem in the validators sample included with wxWidgets and report a bug if you manage to do it there.